# jTemplate currency with 2 decimals

Tags: jquery, jtemplate

I need to display a currency within a jTemplate.

{parseInt($T.product.Details[0].Price).toFixed(2)} displays as 34.50, but i should be displayed with a comma like 34,50.

I tried several functions to replace the point with a comma, but no luck so far. Anyone who can point me in the right direction?

Mark

Answer (score 3):

```
{parseInt($T.product.Details[0].Price).toFixed(2).replace('.',',')}
```